# VBA to import data from closed workbook and paste into specific worksheet as values

Tags: excel, vba, import

I have got a code that works great for importing data from another closed workbook. I have no clue how to modify code so it will paste imported data as values.

Can u please help me to find solution ?

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub Import_SM_Export_DataFromAnotherWorkbook()
 ' Get workbook...
    Dim targetWorkbook As Workbook
    Set targetWorkbook = Application.ThisWorkbook

    ' get the customer workbook
    Dim Filter As String
    Filter = "Text files (*.csv),*.csv"

    Dim Caption As String
    Caption = "Please Select an input Security Matrix file "

    Dim Ret As Variant
    Ret = Application.GetOpenFilename(Filter, , Caption)

    If VarType(Ret) = vbBoolean And Ret = False Then Exit Sub

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Ret)

    'copy into a specific worksheet in your target workbook
    wb.Worksheets(CopyFromHere).UsedRange.Copy targetWorkbook.Worksheets("PasteHere").Range("A1")

    'close opened workbook without saving
    wb.Close SaveChanges:=False
End Sub
```

Comment: You do not import data from a closed workbook... Your code opens the workbook and is able to copy something only after this step. Being a csv file, it has only a single sheet. You can avoid Copy - Paste sequence and replace `wb.Worksheets(CopyFromHere).UsedRange.Copy targetWorkbook.Worksheets("PasteHere").Range("A1")` with `targetWorkbook.Worksheets("PasteHere").Range("A1").Resize(wb.Worksheets(1).UsedRange.Rows.count, wb.Worksheets(1).UsedRange.Columns.count).value = wb.Worksheets(1).UsedRange.value`

Comment: U are absolutely right. It opens closed workbook, copy data and close it:) Anyway this first solution provided works great. It opens, copy data and paste as values and then close source workbook. Great mate. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.PasteSpecial` to paste as Values:

```
wb.Worksheets(CopyFromHere).UsedRange.Copy 
targetWorkbook.Worksheets("PasteHere").Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
```

Also, you should set `Application.CutCopyMode = False` afterwards.

But ideally you'd transfer the data without copy paste entirely. somewhat like this:

```
dim sourceRng as String
sourceRng = wb.Worksheets(CopyFromHere).UsedRange.Address

targetWorkbook.Worksheets("PasteHere").Range(sourceRng).Value = wb.Worksheets(CopyFromHere).Range(sourceRng).Value
```